# Retrofit FieldMap with name

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("addTransaction")
    Call<AddTransactionResult> addTransaction(@Field("userId") String userId,
                                                @Field("portfolioId") String portfolioId,
                                                @Field("symbol") String symbol,
                                                @Field("isCrypto") boolean isCrypto,
                                                @FieldMap("transactionDetails") HashMap<String, Object> transactionDetails);
```

However there is a compile error specifically on:

`@FieldMap("transactionDetails") HashMap<String, Object> transactionDetails);`

Is this even possible with RetroFit? Using the newest version btw!

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `Cannot find method 'value'` @FlorescuCătălin

Comment: @FieldMap should not have ("value").  keys in Map become the key in query params so you should use as `@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> transactionDetails`.

Comment: @Emma which will result in `["transactionDetails" : transactionDetails]` ?

Comment: no. Map's key, value turns into key=value.  For example, your map has `transactionDetails.put("abc", "xyz");` then this results in `abc=xyz`. method argument name doesn't matter.

Comment: I know that @Emma but i want to give the map a name, as there are other parameters in request that are not maps

Comment: You need to nest then. <String, TransactionDetails>.

Comment: got it - thanks @Emma